# Hiding Navigation bar with self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true, hides it permanently

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a `UITableView` object in my view controller and I added the following code inside `viewDidAppear:`:

`self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true`

The navigation bar is hiding when I scroll up, but when I scroll down it's not coming back.

Do I need to do something else?

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986923/hide-navigationbar-when-scrolling-tableview-in-collectionview

Comment: Can you show your auto layout constraint .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default storyboard add tableview top constraint to "Top Layout Guide.Bottom", you need to change the tableview.top constraint to "View.Top"

[image]

Comment: It worked, for others who would need how to add contraints to superview follow this link @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766210/autolayout-add-constraint-to-superview-and-not-top-layout-guide

Answer (score 1):

check your `constraints` for `tableview`. It's `top constraint` should be `pin with superview's top` not with the `toplayoutguide's top`. I think you have set constraint with toplayoutguide. So, try to change it with superview's top and your issue will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to uncheck Extended edges- under top bars to align your UITableView with topLayourGuide. Refer the attachment.[image]