# Hide navigation bar on scroll

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, navbar

I wonder if its OK by iOS Human Interface Guidelines to style a UIView so it looks and acts like a navbar.

My problem is that I want to hide my current navbar once the user scrolls.
I have tried both `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)` and `navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true` but the animation looks odd, once the navigation bar gets hidden I still have about 20px space under the status bar: You can look at my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40166065/swift-calling-setnavigationbarhidden-but-view-wont-move-to-top)

So to make things easier, can I just init my view tih the navbar hidden and style my own and add the proper animation?

Comment: Yes, that's totally fine. Just make sure it's behavior is not unpredictable for iOS users.

Comment: just create the view which looks like navbar & then perfome hide & show. And hide the original nav bar.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40019359/hiding-navigation-bar-with-self-navigationcontroller-hidesbarsonswipe-true-hi/40020151#40020151

Comment: Why is "Swift" part of the question title? This is a framework question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
extension YourViewController {
   override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
      return barsHidden // Custom property
   }

   override func preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation() -> UIStatusBarAnimation {
      return .Slide
   }
}
```

You have to update barsHidden somewhere in the code and call setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() method.