# How to hide navigation bar on scroll except when at the top of the screen

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIViewController` that contains a `UICollectionView` pinned to all edges of the view. This view controller is inside a `UINavigationController`.

I want to gradually hide the navigation bar as I scroll down in the collection view. At the point that I have scrolled the distance of the height of the nav bar, the nav bar should be completely hidden. If I scroll back up it should gradually show the nav bar.

I have tried all the open source navigation bars on github, but none of them work correctly with iOS 12.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: There is nothing available out of the box.. Might need to build a custom navigation bar and use `viewDidScroll` delegate of UIScrollView to compute the hiding and showing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide NavigationBar when scrolling tableView in CollectionView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986923/hide-navigationbar-when-scrolling-tableview-in-collectionview)

Comment: @Harsh It's the "computing the hiding and showing" that I'm unsure of. All the answers in the linked question don't work. I want it exactly how the animation of `AMScrollingNavbar` in the top answer works but that framework doesnt work properly with iOS 11+.

Comment: Fork it and make it work for iOS 11. :)

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` and therefore you have access to its `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method. Your `UIViewController` is also owned by its navigation controller, so you can create an instance property in the view controller, like `navigationDelegate: UINavigationController?`, that will act as a delegate. In the navigation controller, set that property equal to `self` and manipulate the nav bar however you want through the scroll delegate. Absolutely no need for third-party scripting for something this standard and basic.

Comment: In theory, Yes. But when you try it, you can see some troublesome. It can be solved but not as easy as guessing.

Comment: If he wants to post code and get specific, we can do that.